# Does the firmware impact how / if the Hard drive will function (Mac OS X 10.6)?

Tags: hard-drive

I am going to be replacing the Hard drive in my **Mid 2010 Mac Book Pro** (**Snow Leopard 10.6.8**) and I noticed that on the box the Hard drive claims to support **Mountain Lion** or **Higher**. I am wondering if this is just placed there for convenience (claiming to support highest firmware since most people will have it) or if this means that it will not run with OS X 10.6.8?

HD model: WD WDBMYH0010BNC

**Does the firmware impact how / if the Hard drive will function?**

Comment: If you give us the HD model we could help looking it up.

Comment: @Buscar Sure, here is the link...

Comment: http://www.staples.com/WD-WDBMYH0010BNC-Mainstream-for-Laptops-Internal-Hard-Drive-1TB/product_280790?cid=PS:GooglePLAs:280790&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=280790&KPID=280790&kpid=280790&gclid=CjwKEAjw9uypBRD5pMDYtsKxvXcSJACcb9AYDYixkuotyXau1nXT1RJrlLoAwC4W9KLNM3owLi2KOBoCCLPw_wcB

Comment: According to Amazon web site it will work http://www.amazon.com/Western-Digital-2-5-Inch-Mainstream-WDBMYH0010BNC-NRSN/dp/B00D901NX6

Comment: Thanks for the help! -If you provide that as an answer I will up vote / mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Model WD WDBMYH0010BNC

I found multiple places that claim it will work on 10.6.8.

[http://www.amazon.com/Western-Digital-2-5-Inch-Mainstream-WDBMYH0010BNC-NRSN/dp/B00D901NX6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D901NX6)

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8433785